# cursoradapter bindview - Need to use AsyncTask again for faster processing?

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I have implemented the CursorAdapter in my android app, by extending it in my own class and using the newView and bindView methods from the same.
Following is the list of things that I need to do before data is shown to the user -

1) Retrieve image url's (stored in database) in a cursor which is returned by a CursorLoader
2) Get the actual image from the sd card / internal memory by using the url
3) Tie the gridview's column1 which contains an ImageView to the thumbnail image retrieved from the url

Now, here, I am generating the UI elements for GridView in the newView method, whereas binding them with the image in the bindView method. But the problem is that, the image loading is very slow and also, doesn't show up any images till the time, all are not fetched and bound. So, even though the UI doesn't go unresponsive, nothing is shown up for longer time.

**Do we require use of AsyncTask from within the bindView, so as to weave threads and do the image to ImageView binding within AsyncTask rather than directly within bindView??**

What is a correct approach to do an image load for gridview from within the bindView?

External Code link - http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/560756/GeneralSummaryFragment-java.html

Comment: @mkar.ghaisas Please did you find an answer to your question, because i am facing with same challenge. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/33027188/2595059

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask is one good approach here as also advocated by Google 
[Processing Bitmaps off the UI thread.](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)

Comment: Using AsyncTask allows me to side load image at a time, rather than having to wait for all of them to be loaded at once. But the problem is that, on my gridview only 1st 4 items are shown on screen (considering the available space) and there is still the 5th item, which should be basically blank, unless the user scrolls to that item. But, the 5th item, even though not on screen seems to be getting initially bound to 1st item. Then when the user actually scrolls to that item, the image changes from 1st image to 5th item, which is looking weird. Any help on how to resolve would be appreciated.

Comment: Also found that there are total 5 grids rows as per the cursor row count, whereas only 1st 4 are displayed on screen. Even then, for the 5th element, the cursor is resetting to zero and the newView and bindView are called 5th time wherein it then sets the 0th elements value to 5th element, which is why I see that data and image flickering issue.

Comment: @mkar.ghaisas Please did you find an answer to your question