# Image that is set in bindview method behaves funny

Tags: android

I decided to populate my list view with the help of implementing the `Cursor Adapter` and `Cursor Loader` since I am expecting a large number of list contents (many rows) on my activity.

What I am doing right now

1. I first fetch data content from my sqlite database and populate it to the list view through the `bindview` method in my `DotCursorAdapter` inner class which extends the `Cursor Adapter`.
2. Secondly, I asynchronosly download an image from my servers using the Async Task class and set it to the `imageview` through the `bindView` method.

All the above works correctly, but the image which is been downloaded into the `bindview` method behaves funny: Upon execution, the image which is suppose to be set to the, for example, `list item 1` exchanges with `list item 4` and after sometime it gets back to normal by setting the image to its original list item number.

I really do not understand why the image setting is behaving like that. I have sat on this problem for about a week now and I still cannot figure out what the problem is.

My codes for the work above is below, please is there something I am doing wrong or there is a better process to do what I want to do. I would be grateful to know. Thanks for helping.

```
        public class ListViewExample extends Activity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>  {

            DotCursorAdapter mAdapter;
            private ListView lv;
            Context context = this;
            private  final int LOID = 500;
            public static DatabaseHandler dbHelper;



            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_main_activity, frameLayout);
                lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lists);


                mAdapter = new DotCursorAdapter(this, null,1);
                getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOID, null, this);
                lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);


                Urlimage = "http://www.mysiteimage.com/";
            }



            @Override
            public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
                return new DumbLoader(this);
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {


                mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);


            }
            @Override
            public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
                mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
            }


            /**
             * DumbLoader sub class
             */
            public static class DumbLoader extends CursorLoader {


                public DumbLoader(Context context) {
                    super(context);
                }

                @Override
                public Cursor loadInBackground() {
                    Cursor c = dbHelper.fetchAllListViewExample();
                    return c;

                }
            }

            public final class DotCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

                public DotCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
                    super(context, cursor, 0);
                }


                @Override
                public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.ListViewExample, parent, false);
                }


                @Override
                public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

                    /**
                     * image Data from the local database
                     */
                    final String imageName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("msgTitle"));


                    //This is the the image url name 
                    final String imageFull= (Urlimage+imageName);



                    //Place various views variable in the layout view
                    final ImageView imageView= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ciView);


                    //This downloads the image and set it to its view
                    if(imageName== null || imageName.length() == 0|| imageName.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sample);
                    }else{

                        new URLimageDownload(imageView).execute(imageFull);

                    }

                }

            }



            /**
             * This sub class that dowloads the image in the background
             * using the async task.
             */
            private class URLimageDownload extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
                ImageView imageDownloadView;

                public URLimageDownload(ImageView imageDownloadView) {
                    this.imageDownloadView = imageDownloadView;
                }

                protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
                    String urldisplay = urls[0];
                    Bitmap bitmapImage = null;

                    try {
                        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                        bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return bitmapImage;
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                    imageDownloadView.setImageBitmap(result);
                }
            }



        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views are recycled, so as you scroll you make one request, and the response will come asynchronously in the wrong row.

To solve this you should use an Image loader like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

They are both very similar and easy to use:

So replace your bindview for something like this

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(yourUrl)
    .into(myImageView);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked for me. But I prefered Picasso to Glide.

Comment: They are both very good, I switched to Glide because Google officially recommended Glide. There are some small differences in compressing and caching, overall they both do the same thing. http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en